# How could I get properties value from conn_id in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've used var_dup() to check when Codeigniter query do or return after queried any data then I get as below result but all of them just contain null value and 
How can I get the real value from those property?

Example if I want to get value from **warning_count**.

I want to get value from below Object as I dump it from Model.

```
object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)[20]
  public 'conn_id' => 
    object(mysqli)[17]
      public 'affected_rows' => null
      public 'client_info' => null
      public 'client_version' => null
      public 'connect_errno' => null
      public 'connect_error' => null
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'error_list' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'host_info' => null
      public 'info' => null
      public 'insert_id' => null
      public 'server_info' => null
      public 'server_version' => null
      public 'stat' => null
      public 'sqlstate' => null
      public 'protocol_version' => null
      public 'thread_id' => null
      public 'warning_count' => null
  public 'result_id' => 
    object(mysqli_result)[26]
      public 'current_field' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'lengths' => null
      public 'num_rows' => null
      public 'type' => null
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 11
  public 'row_data' => null


 Qquery result

array (size=11)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[27]
      public 'p_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'fk_c_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'fk_group_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'fk_user_id' => null
      public 'manufacturer_id' => null
      public 'stock_status_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'model' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'sku' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'p_name' => string 'asset/img/main/9.jpg' (length=20)
      public 'ean' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'jan' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'isbn' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'mpn' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'location' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'quantity' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'image' => string 'asset/img/main/9.jpg' (length=20)
      public 'shipping' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'price' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
      public 'points' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'tax_class_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'date_available' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
      public 'weight' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
      public 'weight_class_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'length' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
      public 'width' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
      public 'height' => string '0.00000000' (length=10)
      public 'length_class_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'subtract' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'minimum' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'sort_order' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'date_added' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'date_modified' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'viewed' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 =>
```

Model

```
public function selects($data = null, $table = null, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null)
{
    $data = $this->get_data($data, $table, $where, $order, $limit);
    var_dump($data);
    if (!$data) {
        return ['result' => 'There are no data available for you, Sorry!!!'];
    }
    return $data;
}

private function get_data($data = null, $table = null, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null)
{
    if ($this->db->table_exists($table))
    {
        return ['result'=>'This table '.'"'.$table.'"'.' is not existing'];
    }
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $this->db->select($data);
    }
    if (!empty($where)) {
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    if (!empty($order)) {
        $this->db->order_by($order);
    }
    if (!empty($limit)) {
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->_data = $this->db->get();
    if ($this->-data->num_rows() <=0) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

Call in  Controller

```
$this->Products_model->selects('*', 'productsa')->result();
```

Comment: show your query code

Comment: I just dump data before calling Result() method

Comment: All of those properties should be contain any value but why I didnt see it after I've queried data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var_dump($data->conn_id->warning_count);
```

In fact these all properties values are conditional. Like `insert_id` only display last inserted ID when your insert to DB something. Same for warnings & error properties. There are no error & warnings in this query, this is why It showing NULL value.

Comment: No my friend I don't call result method inside Model I will going to use inside Controller because Model method return it as well I main question here I want to get the value property of conn_id as my result data after i var_dump()

Comment: we can do it but I don't know why all of those pro have no value?

Comment: it should be possible to do that. As i my testing I have already get all data which i have selected from DB but those properties still contain Null value.
as I used to develop in another Framework it always contain value.

Comment: In fact these all properties values are conditional. Like `insert_id` only display last inserted ID when your insert to DB something. Same for warnings & error properties. There are no error & warnings in this query, this is why It showing NULL value.

Comment: Ok, So you mean that unless insert and another query method got errors than those properties will initial value but CI right.
so should you tell me some kind of those errors?

Comment: If your code fetch any connect issues, then you can see `connect_errno`, `connect_error`. similar as `http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php`

Comment: Ok now I understand about this properties task why Ci don't public in Document. because it also good for system report